# No Wireless Networks, BCM4313

Tags: 13.04, wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

Just bought this little Asus 10 inch laptop that came with Ubuntu 12.04. Everything at my home was fine: Wireless identified and connected.

As soon as I went to my girlfriend's house the trouble started.

I couldn't connect to wireless (authentication... times out and asks for authentication)

I started doing internet searching, tried a few solutions posted on line using terminal commands.
No solutions. I decided to upgraded to 12.10-13.04 and that left me with a worse problem: I can no longer see ANY networks what so ever.

Wireless card is ON, with out a doubt.
Wired connection works.

I have been fumbling with driver versions to no .avail, and have no idea which driver I am currently running

I have a vague idea of what terminal lines to run:

```
lshw:
  resources: irq:17 memory:f7d00000-f7dfffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
                vendor: Broadcom Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: eth2
                version: 01
                serial: dc:85:de:56:c4:ea
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.20.155.1 (r326264) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
                resources: irq:17 memory:f7d00000-f7d03fff

iwconfig:
eth1      no wireless extensions.

eth2      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I am new and excited to start my Ubuntu and Linux life and this is only the first of my few hic cups i am sure! :) Thanks all

UPDATE: Report from 2nd answer

```
talon@Black1015E:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
[sudo] password for talon: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'bcmwl-kernel-source' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
talon@Black1015E:~$ wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
--2013-10-22 18:50:32--  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
Resolving us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)... 2001:67c:1562::15, 2001:67c:1562::13, 2001:67c:1562::14, ...
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|2001:67c:1562::15|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1181334 (1.1M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb’

100%[======================================>] 1,181,334   3.37MB/s   in 0.3s   

2013-10-22 18:50:33 (3.37 MB/s) - ‘bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb’ saved [1181334/1181334]

talon@Black1015E:~$ arvh
No command 'arvh' found, did you mean:
 Command 'arch' from package 'coreutils' (main)
arvh: command not found
talon@Black1015E:~$ arch
x86_64
talon@Black1015E:~$ sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
(Reading database ... 171895 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (from bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3) ...
Loading new bcmwl-5.100.82.112+bdcom DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.8.0-32-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.8.0-32-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.8.0-32-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod........

DKMS: install completed.
Error: Module b43 is not currently loaded
Error: Module b43legacy is not currently loaded
Error: Module ssb is not currently loaded
Error: Module bcm43xx is not currently loaded
Error: Module brcm80211 is not currently loaded
Error: Module brcmfmac is not currently loaded
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-32-generic
```

rebooting now

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -rv wl
sudo modprobe -v brcmsmac
```

if there are any errors please continue with the commands then reboot. If you have not installed any other drivers but the wl driver then your wireless should be working.

Comment: sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
[sudo] password for talon: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'bcmwl-kernel-source' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
talon@Black1015E:~$ 
talon@Black1015E:~$ 
talon@Black1015E:~$ sudo modprobe -rv wl
FATAL: Module wl not found.
talon@Black1015E:~$ sudo modprobe -v brcmsmac
talon@Black1015E:~$

rebooting now

Comment: Did your wireless come alive if not follow chili555 directions.

Comment: Hey Wildman, it didn't. Now my Wifi isn't even on (confusing)... under the connections drop down its unchecked and greyed out. 

P.S. Thanks for being on these forums man. I saw some of your troubleshooting on posts as I searched for answers. appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 13.04, I believe the default bcmwl-kernel-source will not work correctly for your Broadcom 4313. I recommend that you get a temporary wired ethernet connection and open a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

Or, if yours is a 32-bit system:

```
wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_i386.deb
```

Confirm 32- or 64-bit:

```
arch
```

Then do:

```
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```

Reboot and give us your report.

Detach the ethernet. Is the module wl loaded?

```
lsmod | grep wl
```

If not, load it explicitly:

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

How about now? Does the interface scan?

```
sudo iwlist eth1 scan
```

Comment: Hey Chili, I posted results as an edit because they were too long to put in a comment. It looks like that hasn't solved anything for me.
GUI shows no wireless options what so ever now. Not sure what's up

Comment: iw config shows:
 iwconfig
eth1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

Comment: eth2 is gone :/

Comment: See my edits above.

Comment: The terminal had nothing to say to those commands:
talon@Black1015E:~$ lsmod | grep wl
talon@Black1015E:~$ lsmod | grep wl
talon@Black1015E:~$ sudo modprobe wl
[sudo] password for talon: 
talon@Black1015E:~$ sudo iwlist eth1 scan
eth1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

Comment: Note: Wireless has returned to my GUI, but says hardware switch is off (No switch that I know of!)

Comment: Is there a key combination? Fn+F2, for example?

Comment: Yeah, exactly that chili, but it has no effect on the situation.

Comment: I believe there is a bug with the driver that translates key presses to action for Fn+F2. Please see here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2171494 and here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2173539 Can you unblock the wireless with: sudo rfkill unblock all?

Comment: I attempted rfkill unblock all and no effect. :/

Comment: Frankly, I'd try first and then install 12.04.3 LTS. The problem didn't show up until 13.04 and later.

Comment: Yeah, Hey man thanks for all your help. Appreciate it.